# For loop is not incrementing

Tags: c, for-loop, microcontroller, mplab

I have been working on this code class today and assure  you I have gone through it a number of times. For some reason whenever I set my breakpoints to determine the value of "channelsel" all I get is "0". I never get 1,2,3 or 4 (my MAXCHANNELS is 5).

I'm using: P18F45K22 microcontroller, and mplab c18.

Please take a look at the following code, and thank you in advance

```
int channelsel = 0;
for (channelsel = 0; channelsel < MAXCHANNELS; channelsel++)
    {   
    switch(channelsel)
       {
        case 0:
            SetChanADC(ADC_CH0);
            break;
        case 1:
            SetChanADC(ADC_CH1);
            break;
        case 2: 
            SetChanADC(ADC_CH2);
            break;
        case 3:
            SetChanADC(ADC_CH3);
            break;
        case 4: 
            SetChanADC(ADC_CH4);
            break;
        default:
            SetChanADC(ADC_CH0);
            break;
        }   
    ConvertADC();
    while(BusyADC() == TRUE) Delay1TCY();       
    sampledValue = ReadADC();
    setCurrentTemperatureForChannel(channelsel, sampledValue);
    sprintf (buf, "current Temp of channel %i is %x \n\r", channelsel, sampledValue);
    puts1USART(buf);
    Delay10KTCYx(10);
}
```

Comment: in a header file that i have included in this source file

Comment: this is the statement in my header file  #define MAXCHANNELS 5

Comment: Did hook up the USART wires correctly? Lookes to me like `puts1USART` gets stuck forever.

Comment: I'm certain the wires are in the serial port correctly, but what do you recommend i do?

Comment: Depending on your debugger, try to go through your program - line by line. Try removing suspicious lines (after all this is a short program, so this is still feasable). Initialize your `channelsel` to something different than `0` (so you can distinguish between `stuck-in-loop` and `stuck-before-loop`)

Comment: thank you for the advice. I manually changed channelsel to 1,2,3,4 and it corresponded accordingly, but the same issue came up whereby it wouldn't increment. If i set it to 4 it would stay at 4, 3 would stay at 3 etc.

Comment: whats the signature of the following API `setCurrentTemperatureForChannel`?

Comment: Are you confident that you are making it past `while(BusyADC() == TRUE) Delay1TCY();`?  Further,  I suspect you are simple stuck in one of your routines like `Delay10KTCYx(10)`.

Comment: I declared the variable globally and now it seems to increment properly, thank you for your assistance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Declare channelsel as volatile

```
    volatile int channelsel
```

It is quite likely that your compiler is optimizing away the rest of the statements so that they are not even in the disassembly. When dealing with values that update extremely fast or conditional statements who are in close proximity to the the control values declaration and assignment, *volatile* tells the compiler that we always want a fresh value for this variable and to take any shortcut. Variables that depend on IO should always be declared volatile and cases like this are good candidates for its use. Compilers are all different and your mileage may vary.

If you are sure that your hardware is configured correctly, this would be my suggestion. If in doubt, please post your disassembled code for this segment.

Comment: Cory, I did take a look at that variable and it was declared within the scope of my infinite for loop...i declared it globally and it is now incrementing! Thank you very much for  your assistance!

Comment: You're very welcome. That makes sense although I would advise against using global variables unless absolutely required. I still recommend looking at the disassembly so you can see the "why" of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on PIC18, its a bug that my co-worker discovered, for loops don't work with the c18 compiler, if you change it to a while loop it will work fine.